# Cant see a Permissionset but can see it in a SOQL query

Tags: soql, permission-sets

I can a SOQL query and I see a permission set but when I search for it I can't see it

```
select id, name, iscustom from permissionset
```

[image]

[image]

Any reason why I can't find it?

Comment: did you check the listView filter?

Comment: Sanity check: Are you sure you're querying in the correct org?

Comment: What's the label of the permission set?

Comment: Yeah definitely right org. The label is the same as the Name. yep, I have checked the listview filter. Even tried the All Permssion Sets filter and it doesnt show up.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found out why. The query also includes Permission Set Groups.

I found it there.

[image]